# Do TF2 dedicated servers require special config to allow players to get item drops?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I was planning to set up a Windows dedicated Team Fortress 2 server using [this configuration guide](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Dedicated_server_configuration) and the linked [TF2 Windows Dedicated Server page](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Windows_dedicated_server) from the [official team fortress 2 wiki](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/).

However, I don't see any mention of item drops or any server cvars I should leave alone to avoid breaking them.

So is there any special configuration required (or any settings to avoid, besides the obvious `sv_cheats 1`) for a dedicated server to allow players to receive item drops?

**Edit:** Added links to pages now that I have enough rep to do so.

Comment: Actually I don't think `sv_cheats 1` disables drops.

Comment: really? I assumed that since `sv_cheats 1` normally disables achievements, it would also disable drops

Comment: [this post](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=22597150&postcount=6) implies that you need to turn off `sv_cheats 1` and enter `retry` before you can get drops again, but I'm still surprised drops aren't turned off for the entire match.

Comment: No, `sv_cheats 1` does not disable drops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe item drops are enabled by default. When I create a game or start offline practice on my home computer, I don't need to do anything to start receiving drops.

Answer (score 1):

The only way that you can affect item drop rate is if your server cannot connect to the internet, at which point your clients should not be getting dropped items. Apart from that it's not affected by anything else. timescale, cheats, etc do not affect the drop rate.

Typically if you see "VAC secure mode is activated." at the console after a map change your clients should get drops.